# Ubuntu : Access localhot web in another device

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, localhost

I am testing my frontend design on my pc on localhost:5500 and I want to test it on my mobile, So I have my pc IP address and I am trying to use :5500 to access the web on my phone, but I am unable to do it. (Both devices are connected to the same router.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Are the phone and computer connected to the same local area network?

Is the firewall turned off?

Comment: Yes, both devices are connected to the same network and the firewall is turned off.